# OpenDKIM won't start: "opendkim: milter socket must be specified"

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, amavis, opendkim

I'm trying to setup a server using postfix, dovecot, amavis and opendkim for signing.

OpenDKIM won't start, here is the output of `journalctl -xe`, after stopping and starting opendkim:

```
Jul 21 21:54:17 mail systemd[1]: Starting OpenDKIM DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter...
-- Subject: A start job for unit opendkim.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit opendkim.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 54385.
Jul 21 21:54:17 mail opendkim[108677]: opendkim: milter socket must be specified
Jul 21 21:54:17 mail systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit opendkim.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 78.
Jul 21 21:54:17 mail systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit opendkim.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
```

My OpenDKIM (/etc/opendkim.conf) config looks like this:

```
Syslog              yes
LogResults          yes
LogWhy              yes
SyslogSuccess       yes
UMask               002
Canonicalization    relaxed/relaxed

# Only sign, don't verify (Amavis takes care of the verification)
Mode                s

KeyTable            /etc/opendkim/keytable
SigningTable        refile:/etc/opendkim/signingtable
```

As you could see in the config, I only want OpenDKIM to sign, not verify.

Comment: You've effectively asked a question with the answer in the title...

Comment: @Ginnungagap Well, how should I specify the milter socket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you should specify the socket. The mandatory configuration parameter can be found on [opendkim.conf](http://opendkim.org/opendkim.conf.5.html) documentation:

> **`Socket` *(string)***
>
> Specifies the socket that should be established by the filter to
> receive connections from *sendmail(8)* in order to provide
> service. *socketspec* is in one of two forms:
>
> - `local:path`, which
>   creates a UNIX domain socket at the specified path, or
> - `inet:port[@host]` or `inet6:port[@host]` which
>   creates a TCP socket on the specified *port* and in the specified
>   protocol family.
>
> If the *host* is not given as either a hostname or an
> IP address, the socket will be listening on all interfaces. A literal
> IP address must be enclosed in square brackets. This option is
> mandatory either in the configuration file or on the command line.